# Python regex to find matching brackets

Tags: python, regex

I know I may be asking much, but let's give it a try.

I want to get a regex, that would capture a text between two pairs of brackets.
Let's say that the bracket is `(`:

I want to capture something in this format: ((tt anything_really... ))
Now here are some test cases:

```
((tt da dada))

((tt 
da
dada
))

((tt
da
dada))

((tt
da((da))
dada))

((tt
((this is not))
da
((thi si not))
dada
))

((tt
da
dada
))
((this not))
((capture))
```

I initially came up with something like this:
`\(\(tt.*?\)\)` or `\(\(tt[^\)]+\)\)`.

However, this fails for last two cases(captures `))` too early).

[I've asked a similar question before and got an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225851/match-regular-expression-between-delimiters) however, I don't know how to port these to python, nor if it's possible.

Comment: You can use the regex with the subroutine call with [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) as is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The previous regex doesn't do what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

strings = ['((tt da dada))' ,'((tt da dada ))', '(tt da dada))', '((tt da((da)) dada ))','((tt ((this is not)) da ((thi si not)) dada))']

for s in strings:

    match = re.search(r'(\(\(tt.*\)\))',s)

    if match:
        print match.group(1)
```

Result:

```
((tt da dada))
((tt da dada ))
((tt da((da)) dada ))
((tt ((this is not)) da ((thi si not)) dada))
```

Comment: Yeah, well, I forgot one test case, see that - it's the last one. Your regex fails this test.